# BeautifulSoup String Search

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been googling and looking at other question here on search for a string in a BeautifulSoup object.

Per my searching, the following should detect the string - but it doesn't:

```
strings = soup.find_all(string='Results of Operations and Financial Condition')
```

However, the following detects the string:

```
tags = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'info'})

for tag in tags:

    if re.search('Results of Operations and Financial Condition',tag.text):

    ''' Do Something'''
```

Why does one work and the other not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code

```py
page = urllib.request.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alloxylon_pinnatum')
sp = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page)
print(sp.find_all(string=re.compile('The pinkish-red compound flowerheads'))) # You need to use like this to search within text nodes.
print(sp.find_all(string='The pinkish-red compound flowerheads, known as'))
print(sp.find_all(string='The pinkish-red compound flowerheads, known as ')) #notice space at the end of string
```

Results are -

```
['The pinkish-red compound flowerheads, known as ']
[]
['The pinkish-red compound flowerheads, known as ']
```

It looks like `string` argument searches for exact full string match, not whether some HTML text *node* contains that string, but exact value of the HTML text *node*. You can however use regular expressions to search whether a text node contains some string, as shown in above code.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use:

```
strings = soup.find_all(string=lambda x: 'Results of Operations and Financial Condition' in x)
```

This happens because the implementation of `find_all` looks for the string you search to match exactly. I suppose you might have some other text next to `'Results of Operations and Financial Condition'`.

If you check the docs [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-string-argument) you can see that you can give a function to that `string` param and it seems that the following lines are equivalent:

```
soup.find_all(string='Results of Operations and Financial Condition')
soup.find_all(string=lambda x: x == 'Results of Operations and Financial Condition')
```